# Stacked bar chart with varying widths in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I try to build a stacked bar chart with varying widths, so that the width indicates the mean amount of an allocation, whereas the height indicates the numbers of allocations.

Following, you'll find my reproducible data:

```
procedure = c("method1","method2", "method3", "method4","method1","method2", "method3", "method4","method1","method2", "method3","method4")
sector =c("construction","construction","construction","construction","delivery","delivery","delivery","delivery","service","service","service","service") 
number = c(100,20,10,80,75,80,50,20,20,25,10,4)
amount_mean = c(1,1.2,0.2,0.5,1.3,0.8,1.5,1,0.8,0.6,0.2,0.9) 

data0 = data.frame(procedure, sector, number, amount_mean)
```

When using geom_bar and including widths within aes, I get the following error message:

> ```
> position_stack requires non-overlapping x intervals. Furthermore, the bars are no longer stacked.
> ```

```
bar<-ggplot(data=data0,aes(x=sector,y=number,fill=procedure, width = amount_mean)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

I also looked at the mekko-package, but it seems that this is only for bar charts.

Here is, what I'd like to have in the end (not based on above data):

[image: desired Outcome (not based on above data)]

Any idea how to solve my problem?

Comment: If all else fails, it would be possible to precalculate everything and use `geom_rect`

Comment: How do you want the stacking to be ordered? I'm doing it now with `geom_tile`, which lets you set the center of a rect and then its width and height, but it's looking pretty strange

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have tried the same, `geom_col()` as well but I've run to the same problem - with `position = "stack"` it seems that we can't assign a `width` parameter without unstacking.

But it turned up, that solution is quite simple - we can use `geom_rect()` to build such plot "by hand".

There are your data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  procedure   = rep(paste("method", 1:4), times = 3),
  sector      = rep(c("construction", "delivery", "service"), each = 4),
  amount      = c(100, 20, 10, 80, 75, 80, 50, 20, 20, 25, 10, 4),
  amount_mean = c(1, 1.2, 0.2, 0.5, 1.3, 0.8, 1.5, 1, 0.8, 0.6, 0.2, 0.9)
)
```

At first I have transformed your data set:

```
df <- df |>
  mutate(
      amount_mean = amount_mean / max(amount_mean),
      sector_num  = as.numeric(sector)
  ) |>
  arrange(desc(amount_mean)) |>
  group_by(sector) |>
  mutate(
    xmin = sector_num - amount_mean / 2,
    xmax = sector_num + amount_mean / 2,
    ymin = cumsum(lag(amount, default = 0)), 
    ymax = cumsum(amount)
  ) |>
  ungroup()
```

What I do here:

1. I scaled down `amount_mean`, so the `0 >= amount_mean <= 1` (better for plotting, anyway we don't have another scale to show the real values of `amount_mean`);
2. I also decoded `sector` variable into numerical (for plotting, see below);
3. I've arranged data set in descending order by `amount_mean` (*heavy means* - at the bottom, *light means* on the top);
4. Grouping by sector, I calculated `xmin`, `xmax` to represent the `amount_mean`, and `ymin`, `ymax` for amount. The former two are a bit trickier. `ymax` is obviouse - you just take a *cumulative sum* for all `amount` starting from the first one. You need *cumulative sum* to calculate `ymin` as well, but *starting from 0*. So the first rectangle plotted with `ymin = 0`, second - with `ymin = ymax` of previouse triangle etc.  All of this is performed withing each separate group of `sector`s.

Plot the data:

```
df |>
  ggplot(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax,
             ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, 
             fill = procedure
             )
         ) +
  geom_rect() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = df$sector_num, labels = df$sector) +
  #ggthemes::theme_tufte() +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(title = "Question 51136471", x = "Sector", y = "Amount") +
  theme(
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank()
  )
```

Result:

[image: pyramid_plot]

Another option to prevent to `procedure` variable to be reordered. So all let say "reds" are down, "greens" above etc. But it looks ugly:

```
df <- df |>
  mutate(
      amount_mean = amount_mean / max(amount_mean),
      sector_num = as.numeric(sector)
  ) |>
  arrange(procedure, desc(amount), desc(amount_mean)) |>
  group_by(sector) |>
  mutate(
    xmin = sector_num - amount_mean / 2,
    xmax = sector_num + amount_mean / 2,
    ymin = cumsum(lag(amount, default = 0)), 
    ymax = cumsum(amount)
  ) |>
  ungroup()
```

[image: pyramid_plot_ugly]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your step-by-step explanation. The rescaling of amount_mean gives you great flexibility in design. Perfect.

Comment: I don't know why, but the calculation of ymin and ymax by group doesn't work properly. I always get the cumsum of all values. What could be the problem?

Comment: maybe `dplyr::mutate(...)` would help

Comment: To decode sector variable into numerical, you will need to use `factor`.  That is `sector_num = as.numeric(factor(sector))`